# Jquery get substring of value in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string as such:

```
'newresponse_1__logfile'
```

Note the "1" in the text. It can be 3, 5, etc. It is always between the `_` and `__`.

How can I use jQuery or JavaScript to get the value of the number that is between the `_` and `__`. Note the first is a single underscore `_` and the second a double underscore `__`.

Comment: Please include some code showing what you've tried.

Comment: There are several solutions that work. Please mark an answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `String.split()` :

assuming the number is surrounded by '*' and there is no other '*' before '_{number}__' :

`'newresponse_1__logfile'.split('_')[1]`

and if you want that number to be a `Number` type :

`Number('newresponse_1__logfile'.split('_')[1])`

or

`parseInt('newresponse_1__logfile'.split('_')[1])`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure that the number is surrounded with "_n__", then I would use regex.

```
function getNumberFromFileName(){
  let match = 'newresponse_1__logfile'.match(/_(\d+)__/)
  return match.length ? match[1] : null;
}
```

If you know the number will be there and don't have to check for null you can just do:
`'newresponse_1__logfile'.match(/_(\d+)__/)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var str = "newresponse_1__logfile";

var myString = str.substring(
  str.indexOf("_") + 1, 
  str.lastIndexOf("__")
);

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = myString;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

```
str = "asdf_12__asdf";

var myString = str.substring(
 str.indexOf("_") + 1, 
 str.lastIndexOf("__")
);
```